# Integer value error while importing the kinect library in python

Tags: python, import, kinect, tracking, pykinect

I want to track human, While "`from pykinect import nui`" gives me below error

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykinect\nui\structs.py"
NUI_SKELETON_POSITION_COUNT = JointId.Count.value
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I have installed `pykinect` using this command "`pip install pykinect`", already installed windows `SDK` for `kinect`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was using wrong windows SDK 2.0. I have downloaded SDK 1.8 and it starts working

Answer (score 0):

fyi:
TO USE KINECT 360 Version 1 you need:

python 2.7
windows kinect sdk 1.8
and pykinect    NOT pykinect2

Comment: Not only python 2.7. I've run it on python 3.6 & 3.7